# how to solve css check box checking issue

Tags: html, css

I have made a check box which is used to select various items available to choose from
When any of the check boxes is clicked, the first one get checked leaving the clicked one unchecked.

CSS

```
.checkbox { 
   overflow: hidden; 
   clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
   height:1px; 
   width:1px; 
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   position:absolute;
}
.checkbox + label.label {
   padding-left:20px;
   height:15px; 
   display:inline-block;
   margin-top:3px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position: 0 0;
   font-size:11px;
   vertical-align:middle;
   cursor:pointer;
   float:right;
}
.checkbox:checked + label.label {
   background-position: 0 -15px;
}
.label{
   background-image:url(images/dark-check-green.png);
   color:white;
   font-size:11px;
   font-weight:100;
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="tick" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="tick" name="tick_box" class="label"></label>
```

Comment: Sorry for the error in the first sentence. It is rather "various items available to choose from"

Comment: Is there more HTML that goes with your issue?  Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kN9Wx/

Comment: Are you using the same `for=""` attribute for all the labels? Because then all the labels will toggle the first checkbox, resulting in unwanted and weird behaviour.

Comment: without the for="", the image that is supposed to be displayed when the check box is checked does not display

Comment: ok Thank you very much. it is solved. i had to modify the for="".

Comment: Glad I could help. I've posted my anwser again, so this question can be closed. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same `for=""` attribute for all the labels will result in unwanted and weird behaviour. You should make sure its different for each label + checkbox.

Example:

```
<input id="tick1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="tick1" name="tick_box" class="label"></label>

<input id="tick2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="tick2" name="tick_box" class="label"></label>

<input id="tick3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="tick3" name="tick_box" class="label"></label>
```